# Is it possible to run a simple job in Job Manager in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have written a Flink job that reads data from Kafka and writes to hdfs file in ORC format for HIVE(uses 20 executors). I need to run a simple job that inserts partition to the HIVE table every hour. Is it possible to run this simple partition addition job in job manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job manager only plays a coordinating/supervisory role. You must have at least one task manager.

However, what you can do to run a simple job is to use a "mini-cluster" that runs entirely in the same JVM as the client/application. What you want is a [LocalStreamEnvironment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#local-execution-environment), created by

```java
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
```

or a [LocalEnvironment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/local_execution.html), if you are using the DataSet (batch) API:

```java
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
```

Comment: Is it possible to trigger some events every hour during the stream like using watermark or something else?

Comment: I want to say "yes", but I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do. This seems to be unrelated to this question, so please ask a new question and we can continue there.